# Xcode rebuild doesn’t reflects changes

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build a ionic1 in Xcode for iOS. The problem is any css, html, js changes it doesn't take effect when I rebuild the project.

I notice after 10-15 rebuilds/Xcode restarts I see eventually some edits, not sure what causes that.

Is that a known Xcode/Ionic issue?
How can I solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A process that never fails me is: `ionic prepare ios` (you may need to use `ionic cordova prepare ios` depending on your setup).

I don't even have to close/reopen Xcode - I just wait a few seconds that it loads the changes. Hope this helps.

Comment: I use the latest ionic CLI, it looks like `ionic cordova prepare ios` works!

Answer (score 0):

Probably just need to clean your build folder, `Cmd + Shift + K`, or deleting derived data should help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that an ionic serve session is up and reloading when you make the changes - if it is not make sure you run ionic serve once before you build in Xcode.

All changes will show up.

Doing a clean and rebuild in Xcode is also worth a shot but I think the reason the changes do not show up is because of the ionic serve not being active during changes.

Comment: I tried to build with `ionic serve` running and clean/rebuild, I didn't solved...

Comment: Can you confirm there are no permissions issues on the platforms/ios folder?

Answer (score 0):

First, while you are opening the iOS Simulator, go to 'Device' tab from the simulator menu bar then choose the option 'Erase All Content and Settings'
Second return back to your IDE and do the commands below, I apply them in ios directory:

```
build ionic
```

```
cordova prepare ios
```

then your changes should be reflected with first Clean Build Folder and Build in Xcode